# How can i call a web service using Token Authentication in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

in asp.net, how can i call a web service using Token Authentication:

"For Token Authentication, the client is required to send an access token in a HTTPS “x-apikey” header."
The API supports the following input/output data format: JSON.
Client supplies HTTPS “Accept” header.
Accept: application/json